# Why is x++-+-++x legal but x+++-+++x isn't?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, increment

I'm wondering why in C# the following is fine:

```
int y = x++-+-++x;
```

But

```
int y = x+++-+++x;
```

Isn't?  Why is there a bias against the +?

Comment: Better question is why would you want to use this?

Comment: It depends on the compiler (.Net 4.5 on VS 2012 complains)

Comment: We need specifics on what compiler you're using, what .NET you're targeting, etc

Comment: Yes, why would you want to use this?

Comment: I don't think it should be on hold, it's a legitimate question about C# and is on topic.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable technical question with a specific answer that is not obvious. It should not be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The other two answers are correct; I will add to them that this illustrates some basic principles of lexical analysis:

- The lexical analyzer is *short-sighted* -- it has minimal "look-ahead"
- The lexical analyzer is *greedy* -- it tries to make the longest token it can *right now*.
- The lexical analyzer does not backtrack trying to find alternate solutions when one fails.

These principles imply that `+++x` will be lexed as `++   +   x` and not `+    ++    x`.

The parser will then parse `++ + x` as `++(+x)`, and `(+x)` is not a *variable*, it is a *value*, so it cannot be incremented.

See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/11/10070831.aspx

Comment: +1, although that would make it odd that Mono can compile the same code. Either the spec is a bit "open" on that side, or one of the compilers is not quite up to spec.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Mono has a small bug; I suspect that it is in the semantic analyzer, not the lexical analyzer. That is, it is **not** the case that Mono is lexing `+++x` as `+ ++ x`. Rather, I suspect that it is lexing it correctly as `++ + x`, then the semantic analyzer is treating `+x` as `x`, but forgetting that `+x` is a value, not a variable, and therefore not eligible as an operand of the increment.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Indeed. The Microsoft C# compiler had a number of these sorts of bugs in it in C# 2.0; I removed a lot of them in C# 3.0. A few we kept in because they were harmless and taking the breaking change would have been disruptive.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using VS 2012. This is kind of interesting.

The first one can be parsed into:

```
int y = (x++) - (+(-(++x)));
```

without changing the end result. So you can see why it would be valid.

The second one, however, has an issue with the `+++x` because (I'm guessing) it sees the two ++ and tries to apply that unary operator to the r-value, which is another + (and not a valid r-value). 
You can group it in various ways to make it work, though:

```
int y = (x++)+(-(+(++x)));
```

is valid.

I'm sure Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert or someone will show up and point out the relevant part of the C# spec. I'm not even sure where to start. But just following general left to right token parsing, you could see where it would choke on the second one.

Comment: FYI the whole grammar is at the end of the spec in an appendix.

Comment: Can't see anything but "one of" on the operator grammar, whether to prefer `+` or `++` at any stage seems vague.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Section 2.3 of the spec says *"When several lexical grammar productions match a sequence of characters in a source file, the lexical processing always forms the longest possible lexical element."*

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is looking for a variable or property after the second `++` in `int y = x+++-+++x` and can't determine that without a space or parentheses.

You can do something like:

```
int y = x+++-+(++x);
```

or

```
int y = x++ + -+ ++x;
```

if you wanted.

The reason the first example you listed worked is because the compiler can determine that `+-` from the `++x`; whereas in the second example it can't determine where to separate the `+++` and naturally is expecting a variable after it reads the first `++`; so in short, the compiler trying to use `+x` as a variable, which is invalid.

Both are probably valid using some other compiler.  It depends on the semantics.